# JSON.stringify реобразует время из MSK в GMT

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

JSON.stringify преобразует дату-время в формате московского времени, например, "Sat Apr 25 2020 10:12:42 GMT+0300 (MSK)", а  во время в формате времени GMT, например, "2020-04-25T07:12:42.000Z".

```
function getdateandtime(){
  var DT = Range.getValue() // "Sat Apr 25 2020 10:12:42 GMT+0300 (MSK)"
  var payload = JSON.stringify(DT) // "2020-04-25T07:12:42.000Z"
 }
```

В чем может быть проблема? Как этого избежать? Как  сделать чтобы вернулось московское время? При этом не хочется это делать какой-либо поправкой времени (типа getTimezoneOffset()), а решить системно на уровне форматов или настроек проекта.

Comment: Это не проблема, так и должно быть.

Comment: А как можно передать дату в нужном часовом поясе? Преобразовать дату предварительно в строку?

Comment: Не издеваться над датой и использовать GMT.

Comment: В моем случае это неудобно, т.к. скрипт сначала пишет на лист из БД, не разбираясь в типах, а затем пишет с листа в БД, опять же не разбираясь в типах данных. Хотя ваша мысль хорошая: в случае наличия пользователей из разных часовых поясах удобней использовать GMT (UTC) на сервере и АПИ, а в клиентской части преобразовывать в часовой пояс пользователя.

Comment: Писать в БД, не разбираясь в типах, можно только в вакууме. Это все сломается при активном использовании или при первой попытке масштабирования. Пишите в ISO, и будет вам радость.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Благодаря подсказкам перевел БД на UTC. Так правильнее и удобнее.
2. Чтобы  дата\время в преобразуемом JSON.stringify массиве преобразовалась в отличный от UTC часовой пояс ее нужно предварительно преобразовать из объекта date в строку:

   array_to_stringify['datetime'] = array_to_stringify['datetime'].toStirng()